# Automatically shot photo with integrated camera

Tags: windows, macos, background, camera, privacy

i wonder if it is possible to implement an A) standalone application or B) web-based application/website for computers (PC & MAC) that does automatically shoot a photo with an attached camera (or integrated camera) in the background, without user input?

Is it possible or does one of the platforms (Mac or Windows) see this as violation of user privacy and does not allow that?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a RAT (Remote Administration Tool) to me. Might not be a good idea.

Comment: Maybe the next time you provide some extra source where this is stated. Personal opinions are next to useless on SO. -1